# Python gradient-descent multi-regression - cost increases to infinity

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, gradient-descent

Writing this algorithm for my final year project. Used gradient descent to find the minimum, but instead getting the cost as high as infinity.

I have checked the *gradientDescent* function. I believe that's correct.

The csv I am importing and its formatting is causing some error. 
The data in the CSV is of below format.

Each quad before '|' is a row.

First 3 columns are independent variables x. 
4th column is dependent y.

600 20  0.5 0.63 | 600  20  1   1.5 | 800   20  0.5 0.9

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd

def gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations):
    xTrans = x.transpose()
    for i in range(0, numIterations):
        hypothesis = np.dot(x, theta)
        loss = hypothesis - y
        # avg cost per example (the 2 in 2*m doesn't really matter here.
        # But to be consistent with the gradient, I include it)
        cost = np.sum(loss ** 2) / (2 * m)
        print("Iteration %d | Cost: %f" % (i, cost))
        # avg gradient per example
        gradient = np.dot(xTrans, loss) / m
        # update
        theta = theta - alpha * gradient
    return theta

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\WELCOME\Desktop\FinalYearPaper\ConferencePaper\NewTrain.csv', 'rU', delimiter=",",header=None)

x = df.loc[:,'0':'2'].as_matrix()
y = df[3].as_matrix()

print(x)
print(y)

m, n = np.shape(x)
numIterations= 100
alpha = 0.001
theta = np.ones(n)
theta = gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations)
print(theta)
```

Comment: Why are you setting your delimiter as `,` instead of `|`?

Comment: it might be the delimiter, the data seen to be separated by white spaces.

Comment: @Brayden That's the way to import csv I believe. Let me know what you think?

Comment: @forayer I have mentioned { delimiter=",",header=None }. Do  you think elsewhere?

Comment: @forayer Guess the comments are disabled by the stupid guidelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As forayer mentioned in the comments, the problem is in the line where you read the csv. You are setting `delimiter=","`, which means that python expects each column in your data to be separated by a comma. However, in your data, columns are apparently separated by a whitespace.

Just substitute the line with

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\WELCOME\Desktop\FinalYearPaper\ConferencePaper\NewTrain.csv', 'rU', delimiter=" ",header=None)
```

Comment: Changing it, I get another couple of errors including
<ipython-input-3-4d139340d172> in <module>()
     21 
     22 x = df.loc[:,'0':'2'].as_matrix()
---> 23 y = df[3].as_matrix()
     24 
     25 print(x)

Comment: Could you please paste the error in its entirety? As it is now, it just points out where is the error, but not what it is.

Also, create a csv file containing just the three lines that you put as an example and try to run the program with that as an input.

Comment: Got the above error running now. But new one popped up. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658448/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-dot-product

Comment: Then could you please accept the answer if it solved your issue? That's the standard procedure inside StackExchange websites: it gives credit to the most helpful members of the community and helps visitors to navigate the answers.

Comment: Yeah I accepted your answer. Thanks for helping. But I am really stuck on this one. If you could pls help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658448/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-dot-product