# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars Dot Product

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, gradient-descent

Writing this algorithm for my final year project. Debugged a few, but stuck on this. Tried changing the float method but nothing really changed.

```
----> 8         hypothesis = np.dot(float(x), theta)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Entire code -

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd

def gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations):
    xTrans = x.transpose()
    for i in range(0, numIterations):
        hypothesis = np.dot(x, theta)
        loss = hypothesis - y
        # avg cost per example (the 2 in 2*m doesn't really matter here.
        # But to be consistent with the gradient, I include it)
        cost = np.sum(loss ** 2) / (2 * m)
        print("Iteration %d | Cost: %f" % (i, cost))
        # avg gradient per example
        gradient = np.dot(xTrans, loss) / m
        # update
        theta = theta - alpha * gradient
    return theta

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\WELCOME\Desktop\FinalYearPaper\ConferencePaper\NewTrain.csv', 'rU', delimiter=",",header=None)

x = df.loc[:,'0':'2'].as_matrix()
y = df[3].as_matrix()

print(x)
print(y)

m, n = np.shape(x)
numIterations= 100
alpha = 0.001
theta = np.ones(n)
theta = gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations)
print(theta)
```

Comment: You should provide an example of the csv file you are trying to load. I can run your code using the example you posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640823/python-gradient-descent-multi-regression-cost-increases-to-infinity/49647874?noredirect=1#comment86356018_49647874 with no problem (but with infinity as a result).

Also, you might want to substitute `.as_matrix()` with `.values`, as explained in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-UaU34w3c5-VunYrVz9fD7vRb0c-XDqk/view?usp=sharing Here it is.

Comment: Yes, as you said it's running. But infinity is not desired...

Comment: But your question was about a TypeError...

Comment: yeah, but your answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49640823/python-gradient-descent-multi-regression-cost-increases-to-infinity/49647874?noredirect=1#comment86356018_49647874 isn't running either

Comment: There is a difference between "running" and "giving the expected result". On my machine, this is running but not giving the expected result. This is a typical example of an ill-chosen learning rate: the corrections you make at every step are too big, and the system goes exponentially far from the minimum. Try reducing alpha to 0.000001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` is a numpy array, which Python's builtin `float` function can't handle. Try:

```
hypothesis = np.dot(x.astype(float), theta)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But another one popped up.  x = [['600,20,0.5,0.63']
 ['600,20,1,1.5']
 ['600,20,1.5,1.95'].....] If you could help me out?

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1000,40,1.5,2.67'

Comment: Oh, now I see that `x` contains *rows* of numbers in string format. You might have to specify the data types of each column in your call to `read_csv` to ensure they're imported as numeric, instead of string.